# Problems with sending push notifications

Tags: javascript

There is an iOS application that receives push notifications; for this purpose, a server part was created in Node.js with Firebase cloud functions. There is a standard synchronous function for sending notifications, but it works with great loss, so we are trying to make it asynchronous, but we are faced with a problem.

Below is the code, testing on silent notifications

```
var allMesseges = []
const sendAllMessages = async () => {
  const sendMessege = allMesseges.map(async (message) => {
    let response = await admin.messaging().send(message);
  });
  await Promise.all(sendMessege);
};

exports.allSilentPushTrigerAsync = functions.database.ref('/development/allSilentPushTrigerAsync/').onWrite(async event => {
  let snap = await db.ref("users").once("value")
  let users = snap.val()
  for (const [key, user] of Object.entries(users)) {
    if (user.details.pushToken) {
      const message = {
        apns: {
          headers: {
            "apns-push-type": "background",
            "apns-priority": "5",
          },
          payload: {
            "aps": {
              "content-available": 1
            },
          },
        },
        token: user.details.pushToken,
      };
      allMesseges.push(message)
    }
  }
  await sendAllMessages()
})
```

We get an error in the logs

```
allSilentPushTrigerAsync
pzhv27hvepg4
Error: Requested entity was not found.
at Function.fromServerError (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-    admin/lib/utils/error.js:254:16)
at createFirebaseError (/workspace/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/messaging/messaging-errors-internal.js:35:47)
at /workspace/node_modules/firebase-admin/lib/messaging/messaging-api-request-internal.js:79:75
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
at async /workspace/index.js:180:28
at async Promise.all (index 4)
at async sendAllMessages (/workspace/index.js:182:9)
at async /workspace/index.js:207:10

at async /workspace/index.js:180:28 refers to the line of code:
let response = await admin.messaging().send(message);

at async /workspace/index.js:207:10 refers to the line of code:
await sendAllMessages()
```

Answer (score 0):

1. check the integration with firebase and also check API for notification.
2. check time scheduled on firebase.
3. check Id,The ID to which you want to send the message.
4. input all permission for both android and ios.

```
  IOSInitializationSettings(
    requestAlertPermission: true,
    requestBadgePermission: true,
    requestSoundPermission: true,
  );

    Future<void> _showNotification() async {
  const AndroidNotificationDetails androidPlatformChannelSpecifics =
      AndroidNotificationDetails(
    'your channel ID',
    'your channel name',
    'your channel description',
    importance: Importance.max,
    priority: Priority.high,
  );

  const IOSNotificationDetails iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics =
      IOSNotificationDetails();

  const NotificationDetails platformChannelSpecifics = NotificationDetails(
      android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics,
      iOS: iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics);

  await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
    0,
    'Title here',
    'Body here',
    platformChannelSpecifics,
    payload: 'Custom_Sound',
  );
}
```